# Table in jQuery ui .dialog not following dialog box when moved

Tags: jquery, dialog, position

I'm getting a little better at using the jQuery ui .dialog box, and being bold, and actually reading the documentation on the new ui .position function, though I would give it a try.

There is a large hidden table in my DOM - it becomes "unhidden" when I place it in a .dialog. Here is the code:

```
  $( "#addupdateinsurance" ).dialog({
                                     height: 350,
                                     width: 700,
                                     modal: true,
                                     title: "Add/Update insurance company",
                                     autoOpen: true,
                                     closeOnEscape: true
                                     });
```

This works great. Now I wanted to position it in a particular spot on the DOM and was reading about the "new" .position function. I like the concept of "cascading" and am now using .done after an ajax call instead of the old "success:". So I did this:

```
  $( "#addupdateinsurance" ).dialog({
                                     height: 350,
                                     width: 700,
                                     modal: true,
                                     title: "Add/Update insurance company",
                                     autoOpen: true,
                                     closeOnEscape: true
                                     }).position({
                                                  my:"right center",
                                                  at:"right center",
                                                  of:"#centraldiv" });
```

And it worked, kind of. The dialog moved nicely into the position that I wanted, but left the table behind in another position.

After playing for a while and reading more of the .dialog and .position documentation, I tried the following, which worked beautifully:

```
 $( "#addupdateinsurance" ).dialog({
                                     height: 350,
                                     width: 700,
                                     modal: true,
                                     title: "Add/Update insurance company",
                                     autoOpen: true,
                                     closeOnEscape: true,
                                     position:{my:"right center",
                                               at:"right center",
                                               of:"#centraldiv" }
                                     });
```

So my questions are:

1. In the first instance/error/feature, why isn't the table "bound" to the .dialog when it is placed in the $().dialog() - why doesn't it move with the dialog?
2. Can I use .position in a cascading format with other stuff (divs, spans, etc)?

### Thanks again!

It's kindof big, that's why I didn't put it there first, but here it is:

```
<!--start add/update table-->
<table id="addupdateinsurance" class="addinsurancecotable">
  <tr>
    <td class="tablerjc" style="width:120px" >Company Name:</td><td style="width:200px" class="tableljc"><input id="companyname"></td>
    <td style="width:120px" class="tablerjc">Name Type:</td><td style="width:200px" class="tableljc"><input id="companyname2"></td></tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tablerjc">Company Number:</td><td class="tableljc"><input id="companynum"></td>
    <td class="tablerjc">Intermediary:</td><td class="tableljc"><input id="intermediary"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tablerjc">Street 1:</td><td class="tableljc"><input id="street1" name="street1"></td>
    <td class="tablerjc">Street 2:</td><td class="tableljc"><input id="street2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tablerjc">City:</td><td class="tableljc"><input id="city"></td>
    <td class="tablerjc">State:</td><td class="tableljc"><input id="state" size = "5" name="state">
                            Zip:<input id="zip" size = "8" name="zip"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tablerjc">Elig phone:</td><td class="tableljc"><input id="phoneelig" name="phoneelig"></td>
    <td class="tablerjc">Business phone:</td><td class="tableljc"><input id="phone1" name="phone1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tablerjc">Elig web:</td><td class="tableljc"><input id="siteelig" name="siteelig"></td>
    <td class="tablerjc">Business FAX:</td><td class="tableljc"><input id="fax" name="fax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <button id="resetbutton" style="float:left;">       CLEAR ALL</button>               <!--reset all input-->
      <button id="submitbuttonadd" style="float:right">   Add/Update</button>              <!--add problem-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--end add/update table-->
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.addinsurancecotable {
    height:200px;
    margin:10px auto 10px auto;
    background-color:#E2E4FC;
    display:none;}
.addinsurancecotable td {
    border:0px solid black;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:14px;}
```

Comment: html/css for your table? can you please elaborate if you want to move table along with dialog? is it inside #addupdateinsurance element?

Comment: Thanks for responding! I edited the post with the full table and styling for it. And yes, I consider the table and integral part of the dialog - they should be "bound".

Comment: I see everything fine. Am I missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/x4zry/

Comment: It's working fine now, when I add the positioning INSIDE the .dialog function. When I tag on the dialog function with .position $(xxx).dialog({stuff}).position({stuff}), the dialog moves, but what is inside it (the table) does not. I'm curious about why that might be.

Comment: Hmmmm...I'm using jQuery UI 1.10.3 with jquery 1.9.1 - I wonder if that is the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your css as :

```
    #centraldiv{
          position:relative;

        }
.addinsurancecotable {
            height:200px;
            margin:10px auto 10px auto;
            background-color:#E2E4FC;
            display:none;
            position:absolute;
        }
.addinsurancecotable td {
            border:0px solid black;
            font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            font-size:14px;}
```

see [here](http://jsbin.com/ovUFOZA/4/)